# Define primary/warn palette in other than config function at runtime

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

Hi I am trying to use angular material $mdthemingprovider to apply theme to my website dynamically.

I have injected **$mdThemingProvider** inside config function as below.

```
    angular.module('my-module').
config(function ($provide, $mdThemingProvider) {
    $provide.value('themeProvider', $mdThemingProvider);})
```

Now as said in [dynamic theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602668/dynamically-loading-a-material-theme-in-angular) I have injected **themeProvider** in my controller. I am trying to define primary, accent, warn, palette first and then registered theme and then tried to set newly registered theme in following way.

```
     var customPrimary = {
        '50': '#ff7b82',
        '100': '#ff626a',
        '200': '#ff4852',
        '300': '#ff2f3a',
        '400': '#ff1522',
        '500': '#fb000d',
        '600': '#e1000c',
        '700': '#c8000a',
        '800': '#ae0009',
        '900': '#950008',
        'A100': '#ff959a',
        'A200': '#ffaeb3',
        'A400': '#ffc8cb',
        'A700': '#7b0006'
    };

    themeProvider
        .definePalette('customPrimary', 
                        customPrimary);

    var customAccent = {
        '50': '#000a08',
        '100': '#00231d',
        '200': '#003d31',
        '300': '#005646',
        '400': '#00705a',
        '500': '#00896f',
        '600': '#00bc97',
        '700': '#00d6ac',
        '800': '#00efc0',
        '900': '#0affcf',
        'A100': '#00bc97',
        'A200': '#00a383',
        'A400': '#00896f',
        'A700': '#23ffd4'
    };
    themeProvider
        .definePalette('customAccent', 
                        customAccent);

    var customBackground = {
        '50': '#737373',
        '100': '#666666',
        '200': '#595959',
        '300': '#4d4d4d',
        '400': '#404040',
        '500': '#333',
        '600': '#262626',
        '700': '#1a1a1a',
        '800': '#0d0d0d',
        '900': '#000000',
        'A100': '#808080',
        'A200': '#8c8c8c',
        'A400': '#999999',
        'A700': '#000000'
    };

    themeProvider.definePalette('customBackground',customBackground);
    themeProvider.theme('custom')
`.primaryPalette('customPrimary'')
   accentPalette('customAccent')
 .backgroundPalette('customBackground');`
 `themeProvider.setDefaultTheme('custom');`
```

I can see '*custom*' theme is applied in firebug mode at elements level like div . But colors are not getting applied.

But if I am setting *primaryPalette*, *accentPalette* ,*backgroundPalette* directly with any color like below way, colors are getting reflected in web pages.

```
  `  themeProvider.theme('custom')
  .primaryPalette('red')
  .accentPalette('yellow')
  .backgroundPalette('blue');

themeProvider.setDefaultTheme('custom');
```

So it seems definePalette method is not working with instance themeProvider.

```
themeProvider.definePalette('customBackground',customBackground);`
```

and palette is not getting defined.

Can anyone guide me how to define custom palette in controller.

Comment: The palette is generated, if you check on `console.log(themeProvider._PALETTES);` you can see that the palette is defined in there. The problem is that you can only define a palette on the application config, not on the controller. Currently on the controller what I have found is that if you extend one of the defined colors. `var red = themeProvider.extendPalette('red', {
          });` then substitute all color values of the value section `red['50'].value = [255, 255, 0]` and finally define that color as your palette `themeProvider.definePalette('customColor', red);` then it will be usable.