# Change a theme using angular.js on runtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I want to change the theme of my angular.js app on runtime I already made the theme providers settings, but they are not applied, what I have on my code is:

```
.controller('ApplicationController', function (
    $scope, 
    themeProvider, 
    $mdTheming,
    SomeService) {

    SomeService.Init()
        .then(function(res) 
        {
            var customPrimary = {
                '50': '#FFFFF',
                '100': '#FFFFF',
                '200': '#FFFFF',
                '300': '#FFFFF',
                '400': '#FFFFF',
                '500': '#FFFFF',
                '600': '#FFFFF',
                '700': '#FFFFF',
                '800': '#FFFFF',
                '900': '#FFFFF',
                'A100': '#FFFFF',
                'A200': '#FFFFF',
                'A400': '#FFFFF',
                'A700': '#FFFFF'
            };
            themeProvider
            .definePalette('palettePrimary',
                customPrimary);

            var customSecondary = {
                '50': '#FFFFF',
                '100': '#FFFFF',
                '200': '#FFFFF',
                '300': '#FFFFF',
                '400': '#FFFFF',
                '500': '#FFFFF',
                '600': '#FFFFF',
                '700': '#FFFFF',
                '800': '#FFFFF',
                '900': '#FFFFF',
                'A100': '#FFFFF',
                'A200': '#FFFFF',
                'A400': '#FFFFF',
                'A700': '#FFFFF'
            };
            themeProvider
                .definePalette('paletteSecondary',
                    customSecondary);

            themeProvider
                .theme('alternative')
                    .primaryPalette('palettePrimary')
                    .accentPalette('paletteSecondary')
                ;

            $mdTheming.generateTheme('alternative');
            themeProvider.setDefaultTheme('alternative');
        }
    );
}
```

As you can see the change of the colors depends of a service but when it's executed nothing changes.

If I set the colors outside the Service it seems to work but there's no change on the template.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically loading a material theme in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602668/dynamically-loading-a-material-theme-in-angular)

Comment: I'm testing the method described on you link but's not working, looking for alternatives :)