# Angular JS: Unknown provider: $mdThemingProviderProvider <- $mdThemingProvider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material, angularjs-provider

When the High Contrast Mode is on, I need to use the dark theme and is working as below:

```
$mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
            .primaryPalette('green')
            .accentPalette('orange', {
                'hue-3': 'A700'
            }).dark();
```

But, I need to apply **.dark()** only when some condition is true and that data is available in controller only. Is there a way to apply the **.dark()** over the theme from the controller?

I tried to inject `ngMaterial` in the controller's module and `$mdThemingProvider` as dependency in that controller and copy-pasted above code but getting below error:

> Unknown provider: $mdThemingProviderProvider <- $mdThemingProvider

Comment: Can you show us how you are injecting the provider?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40857431/548997).